# How to split JSON output and get fields into variable in Java?

Tags: java, json, spring

I executed this line of code segment.

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(ezCashDynamicQRIntegration(axiPayQrCodePayment, serviceContext).getBody());
```

So that Output is following JSON

```
{ "qrContent":"DQRC|CARGILLS|Cargills|1000.00|TX_AOTC|TXN_00001|https://test.url|remark",
   "message":{  
      "code":"040",
      "description":"verified"
   },
   "status":"SUCCESS"
}
```

Following i executed this line of code

```
        qrContent = (String) object.get("qrContent");
        log.info("QR CONTENT IS {} ",qrContent);
        messageContent = (String) object.get("message");
        log.info("MESSAGE CONTENT IS {} ",messageContent);
```

Log will print out

> QR CONTENT IS
>   DQRC|CARGILLS|Cargills|1000.00|TX_AOTC|TXN_00001|https://test.url|remark

But nothing is message content. can anyone help me why this?

Comment: The message property is a JSON object, not a string. So you probaly get a ClassCastException, telling you precisely that.

Comment: So how can i fix that?

Comment: By not casting the result of `object.get("message")` to a String, since you know that this cast is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In your code line 
 `messageContent = (String) object.get("message");`

you are casting org.json.JSONObject to String. It should throw an exception like, `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

change the line to 
 `messageContent = object.get("message").toString();`

Comment: Or Can i use this? JSONObject messageN = new JSONObject(object.get("message")); and then messageContent = (String) messageN.get("code");

Comment: when you using, messageContent = object.get("message").toString(); you are calling the toString method of org.json.JSONObject. It will convert the contain to string

Comment: JSONObject messageN = new JSONObject(object.get("message")); will create another JSONObject, And it will create an epty JSONObject, will log as {}, Because object.get("message") will give an object, but you are think that will be an String. why to create another object to just for log. just call the toString();

Comment: if i use toString() can i get its code value and the description values  into separated variables.?

Comment: Nop toString() will return in string format. if you need to take code description values into separated variables, ```String code = object.getJSONObject("message").get("code").toString();
        String description = object.getJSONObject("message").get("description").toString();```

Comment: If this is an reusable functionality, create a POJO object for response. Then convert the json to pojo object.

Comment: Bro I have a POJO object called Message and 2 fields of String code and description. if i set  message.setCode(code);
            message.setDescription(description);
            log.info("Message is ------------- {} ",message);.... this log also not get printed.

Comment: Override and implement the toString method in your POJO class

Comment: if the message object is not empty it should print. debug the app and check the message object when logging.

Comment: Problem is i cant debug this app locally. always have to put a build see the logs. if it wont this ll easy.

Comment: How can be thet message object empty? um setting the values um getting noh